How can I build android chromium for linux without sudo permission to install those dependencies?
To build android chromium, there is a script to install additional build dependencies that require sudo permission. But I am planning to do in other instance which don't have the root permission. Is there any other way to skip this sudo permission and let it build successfully?
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Install-additional-build-dependencies
Tried

I have tried to build with the packages dependencies originally installed in the server, but it is not enough to support this chromium build.

Tried to package them into a tar file with all dependencies, but seems like not working


Expecting
Get rid from the sudo permission request and build successfully for it
